# My question is getting closed for questionable reasons

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Okay, so I made a question about the absence of gotos in javascript:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190070/i-wish-javascript-had-a-goto

It got closed because it "wasn't a real question". So, I reposted it and emphasized my two questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190242/someone-explain-to-me-the-absence-of-gotos-in-javascript

This one got closed for being an exact duplicate of the previous one. Clearly the discussion should only be continued in one of the two questions, but the first one *was already closed* yet some folks used the fact that it existed as an excuse to close the second one. ONE of them should not be closed, not BOTH.

Can someone help me out here and explain what's going on?

**EDIT:** Some folks have locked my second question again for being a duplicate question. I don't get it. So, now I've had the original question deleted just to get it over with. (It wasn't doing anyone any good anyway.) Could anyone unlock my question again now that it is no longer a duplicate?

Thank you.

Comment: When a question is closed, and you feel it's because of the wording, the correct way is to edit the question to make it better, and maybe to flag it to get reopened. Don't post a duplicate.

Comment: @Gnou you can flag for reopening? Do mods really step into the community process like that so directly?

Comment: How do I flag to get it reopened and in the current circumstances what do you advocate?

Comment: @Earlz - true, take my comment on the conditional, this is valid for Super User, I don't know for Stack Overflow, with the higher volume.

Comment: @Earlz, @Gnoupi: I've done it before.  If the reasons that the question was closed are completely removed, I see no reason not to give it another chance.  I do have a strict personal policy of only doing this once for a given question though.  If the community overrides me and closes it again, I'll stay out of it.

Comment: Well, I hope your question gets re-opened because there is a way to do GOTO in JavaScript and I have your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question was barely detectable under a thick layer of editorial commentary.

Consider this alternative wording, amongst many others:

> I'm accustomed to using gotos in some
>   cases to get readable code for
>   exceptional flow of control.
>   Javascript has no goto, and everything
>   I thought of looks baroque. What is a
>   clean way to express this flow without
>   goto?

If you pose that question, you might get a few snarky comments, and for all I know there's a perfectly fine duplicate that someone will dig up, but you won't be closed the way you were today.

Your second question was just as rant-y as your first:

> Pretty simple. My code now has FSMs
>   and crud like this in order to get a
>   goto-like construct thanks to the lack
>   of gotos.

Thus the dup. When you post one that just asks the question without blogging your opinions about the language, it probably won't be closed.

**EDIT**

Slightly chagrined by a comment from the OP, I want to emphasize that my purpose here is to channel my observations about the community's standards in the clearest possible terms. This  is my best effort to clearly explain the community's 'thought' process in closing these questions. As one of the close voters, I'm certainly in the loop on this occasion for this question, but please don't mistake my Oracle of Delphi act here.

Comment: My questions were explicitly pointed out in the "closed duplicate." Yes, I am pointing out the circumstances that motivated me to ask the question and my opinions on the matter - I find them relevant. What's the problem?

Comment: You find your circumstances and opinions relevant. 5 of us found them rants. You have now learned how the community standards of stackoverflow.com work. It's your choice what to do with this information. You can adapt to the local mores, or you can have your questions closed. What you can't do is change the mores by force of will.

Comment: Rosinante, if you could avoid the heavy-handed, authoritarian tone of voice, I'd appreciate it. Anyway, edited the post again. How is this?

Comment: @Anonymous: It's hard to hear that you are wrong but what he is trying to point out is that your original question was quite rant-y and it could have been described much more succinctly.

Comment: No, I don't mind blunt criticism. To the contrary, I very, *very* freely encourage it. I *do* mind when people criticize in a way that makes it sound like I don't matter and I should either bow down to their wishes or leave. When it's worded like that, like Rosinante did in the above comment, yes, I find it somewhat difficult to tolerate. I freely acknowledge the original was rant-y. I've also been trying to reword it since to be less rant-y without having to remove content. At this stage, however, it seems like the main issue is the "duplicate question" mess which shouldn't apply anymore.

Comment: @Ano You mistake my attempt to paint reality in very clear terms with an attempt to browbeat you. This isn't about *me*, even though I happen to have been voter this time. The community is swift and merciless on this sort of thing, for better or for worse -- in a sense, censorious and authoritarian, yes.

Comment: @Anonymous: Tone is hard to convey. But, like Rosinante said, SO is meant to create the best programming resource. If the questions or answers are poor, then they will be pummeled to death by downvoting and closing.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to get it answered and have it stay open, edit your question to remove the rant.

If your goal is to rant and have your question closed, then keep it as-is.

Here's my suggested edit:

> How do I achieve the 'goto' construct in JavaScript?
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> myGoto:
> do {
>     for (j=0; j<entries.length; j++) {
>     if (entries[j]==tempEntry) break myGoto
>     }
>     entries[++k]=tempEntry
> } while (false)
> ```

Comment: Where's the rant? Sure, the original was kinda rant-y, but my repost, to my eyes, *wasn't*.

Comment: See your writing, specifically the tag, `cruft`;  "Thanks to the lack of Gotos"; and "Why the heck couldn't I just get a Goto to get this done normally?"

Comment: @Ano: The repost was a repost, and therefore a duplicate. We try to only have one incarnation of each question around. Also  reposting can easily be perceived as a reaction like "If you close my question I just post it again!!!", which people don't like. Improving the original question and voting to reopen it would usually be the accepted way of going about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're basically correct:

- **Your first post was closed as more of a rant than a question, which is ok.**   The closing process is "subjective-by-design" (a new tag proposal!) - it's up to high rep-users and the community at large to determine when questions are not helpful / appropriate.
- **Since your second question's only crime appears to be overlap with a question that essentially was deemed non-existant, it probably should  be allowed.**  It was still a *little* editorial, but I did see two clear questions, which is why I suspect it *wasn't* closed for being a fake question.

(At a minimum, the *reason* the second question was closed seems unfair.  If it's also deemed to be "not a real question, okay- see my subjective-by-design point above.    But if it *is* a real quesiton, then it seems like it can't be appropriate to delete it for being exactly the same as one that wasn't.)

Comment: There is no "user can't find edit button" close reason...

Comment: Shog, what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @shog9 means, this user should have fixed his original post through editing rather than reposting yet more stufff.

Answer (score 2):

**In General**

Questions can, and sometimes should be closed as exact duplicates of other closed questions. This is because if the first one was closed as invalid for some reason, then the duplicate question would *usually* have the same flaws.

As mentioned a few times, the best response to getting a question closed would be.

1. Edit to *dramatically* improve the question.
2. If there is no movement after a few hours (minimum), take it to meta.
3. If there is no movement from meta, it *might* be possible to create a unique question using what you have learned, so as to not offend the sometimes delicate sensibilities of the SO community.

Note about step 3: **DO NOT** recreate your original question. It has already been closed, and your new question should be marked as a duplicate. The best solution would be to look at your problem from a new angle, and post that as your question to StackOverflow.

**In Your Case**

Two things repeatedly got in your way. The editorial commentary which other people considered to be a rant, but you considered to be context: this is usually frowned upon. If your question is technical but unorthodox, you *should* explain why you have the limitations you have, but you don't need to give them information about everything you are doing unless the comments ask for further information.

**NEVER** include anything aggressive or even something people could perceive as aggressive (if you can help it). The community tends to react very harshly to anything like that. Is this desired behaviour? Certainly not, but it exists and you should be aware of it.

Linking back to your original post was unhelpful, because it made it very clear that you had simply posted the same question twice. As I mentioned earlier, duplicates are very much frowned up on StackOverflow, because there are more than enough accidental duplicates, so purposeful duplicates *seem* maliciously wasteful of people's time.

Another item which interfered was that you mingled two **very** distinct questions into one. "Why doesn't javascript have goto" and "How should I refactor my code".
Question 1 amounts to "I wish I had a goto" which falls under "rant/subjective" and shouldn't be on SO. Question 2 is more valid, and that is where you should have restricted your focus.

You had an actual technical issue, and the context doesn't really matter, so it doesn't matter that javascript doesn't have `goto` it only matters what you are trying to accomplish. If you focus on that, you'll have much more success.